# Can you please move this question to english.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, status-completed

I accidently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578517/whats-the-difference-between-a-tune-and-a-melody) on stackoverflow and got a good answer there; it wouldn't be fair toward the answerer to delete it. It is already closed, but I think it would still be good to have it here on "English" territory.

Answer (score 7):

I have migrated the question. In general you should flag for moderator attention on the site that the question was originally asked on, for three reasons:

1. Moderators can only migrate *away* from their site rather than *to* it.
2. Normal users who vote to close the question can migrate between some sites but not between Stack Overflow and English Language & Usage.
3. Flagging for moderator attention will alert even moderators who do not check the meta sites often.

Answer (score 4):

Administrators of this site do not have the necessary permissions to migrate questions from SO to here. It would have to be done by one of the site developers.

Comment: No @Nohat, every mod now has the ability to migrate a question to any destination, through the mod tools on a question